# junit - local test method override - @BeforeClass

Tags: junit

How to set one of the test method value different than all other test methods. I want to set subclass Test1's testName2() test method's name is local instead of global.

```
public class Test {

 @BeforeClass
 public static void setGlobalValues() {
    System.setProperty("name", "global");
 }
}


public class Test1 extends Test {
  @Test
  public void testName1() {

  }

  @Test
  public void testName2() {
      System.setProperty("name", "local");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Before` instead of `@BeforeClass`. Then every test has the value `global` and only `Test1.testName2` has the value `local`.

By the way you should reset the property after your test. The library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules) provides JUnit rules for this.